# Make some sums and multiplications with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to sum some values in a form, i have not managed to get anywhere:

As you can see, there are 3 checkboxes, 3 radio buttons and 1 select dropdown

i need to sum the selected checkboxes, multiply by one of the radio values and sum at the end the value from the selected box. Have no clue on how to do it :/

Can i save the result in an object? not a json object but javascript

```
<div class="reciright">
        <form id="formi">
        <div class="recil">
            <span class="ltitle">Extras incluídos:</span>
            <div class="recheck"><input class="acc1" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="0.4" /> Caixa original</div>
            <div class="recheck"><input class="acc2" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="1" /> Cabo e carregador</div>
            <div class="recheck"><input class="acc3" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="3" /> Auscultadores</div>

            <span class="ltitle">Estado Geral:</span>
            <div class="recheck"><input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="0.5" /> 100% Funcional</div>
            <div class="recheck"><input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="0.4" /> Funcional mas não a 100%</div>
            <div class="recheck"><input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="0.3" /> Avariado</div>


        </div>

        <div class="recir">
            <span class="ltitle">Dados do Equipamento:</span>
            <div class="recampos">N.de Serie</div> <input class="inputix" type="text" name="fname" id="nserie">
            <p><div class="recampos">Modelo:</div><select class="selectit" id="modelo">
            <option value="50">iPad 2 wifi</option>
            <option value="20">iPad 1</option>
            <option value="10">iPad 2</option>
            <option value="1">iPad 3</option>
        </select></p>

            <div class="recampos2">Breve descricao do equipamento</div>
            <textarea rows="3" cols="50" class="recitextarea"></textarea>

        </div>
        <div class="icecream"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: wat have u tried so far?

Comment: i was trying to come up with a solution,

var sup = $(this).val();

get all the variables this way

Comment: JSON = **JavaScript** Object Notation

but for what it's worth unless I'm missing something in your question you can just store the result in a variable.

Comment: @Jared: JSON **is not** JavaScript. An object is a datatype in JavaScript, JSON is a general purpose data exchange format.

Comment: @FelixKling That was what i've read arround. Thanks for exposing the concept in a clear way.

Comment: @FelixKling JSON *is* a subset of JavaScript, therefore valid JSON is valid JavaScript but not the other way around. That was what Jared was referring to.

Comment: @Torsten: One always has to be careful when mentioning JSON together with JavaScript. Yes, the JSON syntax is a subset of JavaScript's object literal syntax and yes, if JSON is *evaluated as* JavaScript ( with some adjustments (adding parenthesis)) then it is valid, but it is not JavaScript. And if someone says "I want a JS object and not JSON", then making a comment implying that these two things are one and the same (at least that's how I interpreted it) is just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
$("#modelo, [type='checkbox'], [type='radio']").on('change', function() {
    var boxvalue = 0,
        boxes = $("[type='checkbox']", "#formi").filter(':checked'),
        radios = parseFloat($("[type='radio']").filter(':checked').val()) || 1,
        dropdown = parseFloat($("#modelo").val()) || 1;

    $.each(boxes, function() {
        boxvalue+=parseFloat(this.value)||0;
    });

    var sum = (boxvalue * radios) * dropdown;

    $("#nserie").val(sum);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XzEP4/)
    ​

Comment: Just great, to say the least :D!

Thank you very very much adeneo, selected as the right answer!